# How to access AssetResponse properties of a newly created asset? C# or Java

Tags: assets, java-sdk, c#-sdk

I'm using the C# SDK.

For Example, a new Asset is created.

`_stellarAsset = Asset.CreateNonNativeAsset("credit_alphanum4", _assetIssuer, _assetCode);`

This is in a method which returns the asset that was just created.

Now I need to access `_stellarAsset.Asset` or `_stellarAsset.Code` however, those properties only exist in the `AssetResponse` class. This might have an obvious answer but how can I get access to `AssetResponse` properties from the newly created Asset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Asset.CreateNonNativeAsset` is a simple factory method to create an Asset instance of the right subtype.

https://github.com/elucidsoft/dotnet-stellar-sdk/blob/master/stellar-dotnet-sdk/Asset.cs#L19-L29

The values for `code` and `issuer` will be the same as the values you provided as parameters.

I suspect the reason you cannot access these values on the returned type is because the parent type `Asset` is returned. It is realised in subtypes by `AssetTypeNative`, `AssetTypeCreditAlphaNum4` and `AssetTypeCreditAlphaNum12`. The first of these three do not have `code` and `issuer` values, so the parent type doesn't have it either. I'm not familiar with C#, but I suspect you would need to detect the subtype and cast it before you can access the fields.

From memory, this is the approach taken in Java SDK too.

As an aside, I chose to use a different hierarchy when building the Scala SDK in order to avoid type problems like you describe:

```
Asset
 + NativeAsset
 + NonNativeAsset(code, issuer)
   + IssuedAsset4
   + IssuedAsset12
```

`Asset(code, issuer)` only returns instances of `NonNativeAsset`. In this way you can always pattern match or directly access the fields:

```
@ Asset("FRUIT", KeyPair.random) match {
    case IssuedAsset4(code, issuer) => s"$code from ${issuer.accountId}"
    case IssuedAsset12(code, issuer) => s"$code from ${issuer.accountId}"
  }
res5: String = "FRUIT from GAKNBE6KCPJQZMJQCDVYNSSQU5B4BWIHGSDRBSHGYLWHE2D5H3TRWTUK"
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. I'll just adjust logic to query Horizon for the provided asset and pick from the results instead with the `AssetResponse` type. I was basing my logic off of the JavaScript SDK when those areas where the c# and java docs weren't as detailed. In that SDK, account code and issuer are properties of any asset instance.